# HTML Email - Tappable street address in Android

Tags: android, html-email

If I send an email to an iOS device with

```
Business Name
Street Address 1
City, State, Zip
```

iOS will see that address and optionally make it tappable to open Apple Maps. However, that doesn't always seem to be the case for Android. As best I can tell, it comes down to the actual formatting of the address, the Android OS version, and the email app that's used to open the email. But, is there some special markup I can use otherwise? Similar to the phone: anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done, I had done this sometime ago for a previous company I used to work with.

Say for example you have a company in North Sydney Australia called Dashing, its a printing company. You link will be as follows:

```css
span{font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;}
```

```html
<span>The address is: <a href="https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Dashing+Berry+Street+North+Sydney+New+South+Wales" style="color:#ff0000" target="_blank">1/53 Berry St, North Sydney NSW 2060</a>, click the address will take you places.</span>
```

Clicking the above link will take you to google maps to show the location. This is handy if you are making emails for a hotel group and you want to show links. I used to take it a step further and display the hotels location as an image and link it. The above code should work for both iOS and Android.

Let me know if this is what you were after.

*ps: The CSS is just so i don't see Times New Roman :-)*